# Laravel Join Query Separately for each currency

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have wallets table like that:

```
user_id     amount       currency
1           100          EUR
2           50           USD
2           200          AUD
2           120          EUR
```

So I need something like that:

```
User::select('users.*', 'wallets.amount')
        ->leftJoin('wallets.amount as eur', [['wallets.user_id', '=', 'users.id'], ['wallets.currency', '=', 'eur']]);
        ->leftJoin('wallets.amount as usd', [['wallets.user_id', '=', 'users.id'], ['wallets.currency', '=', 'usd']]);
```

To explain more, I need query which will sellect all users, and then in wallets table to separately select eur, usd, aud for this user. So I can have "user.eur, user.usd".

Comment: In your solution, you are hardcoding the currency value, while in the DB table it is a dynamic value, not linked to a column or another table, you should rethink this as it is not a good pattern

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Im using bavix/laravel-wallet, trying to connect yajra datatables to be able to sort by user wallet  currency, in 'users' page @Greedo

Comment: yes ok, but my point is that you should not hardcode the currencies in your PHP, while they are normal values (not column) in your SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
User::select('users.*','wallets.amount')
    ->leftJoin('wallets',function ($join) {
                $join->on('wallets.user_id', '=' , 'users.id') ;
                $join->where('wallets.currency','=','eur');
                $join->where('wallets.currency','=','usd');
        });
```

Comment: Now when I do foreach, how can I separately write amount in eur, usd?

Comment: fist of all give me your output..in your question.

Comment: this provided as example in my question is not working

Comment: I need to get foreach of all users and able to store for each user wallet balance in eur, usd separately, if you get me

Comment: ->leftJoin('wallets as eur', function ($join) {
                        $join->on('wallets.user_id', '=', 'users.id');
                        $join->where('wallets.currency', '=', 'eur');
                    })
                    ->leftJoin('wallets as usd', function ($join) {
                        $join->on('wallets.user_id', '=', 'users.id');
                        $join->where('wallets.currency', '=', 'usd');
                    });

something like this